How do you hide a link in react?
I have a user componenet that has a link to a user page/profile. As it is used all over the application to display users, there are some cases where I just want to display the user info, but omit the link to the user's profile page.
The problem is that, apparently you cannot put an incomplete tag into a JSX expression. Since the Link tag needs to encompass the entire body that will become the link, this doesn't really work. This seems like a linter bug, because there are plenty of cases where this seems legit. The problem is, how do I cleanly make this work?
Here is a code sample, showing what I would like to achieve:
interface UserAvatar {
  id: number;
  screenName: string;
  displayUserLink: boolean;
}

const UserAvatar = ({ id, screenName, displayUserLink }: UserAvatar) => {
  return (
    {displayUserLink && (<Link to={'/users/' + id} >)}
      <div>{screenName} AND A WHOLE BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF...</div>
    {displayUserLink && (</Link>)}
  );
};

export default UserAvatar;

If fails because the Link tag isn't closed. What is the best workaround to achieve this goal?
Note that there is a whole lot more being rendered next to the screen name, so this is not a simple string that can be dropped inside the link to render as a simple anchor tag. I just omitted the inner guts to demonstrate the core problem.
Solution
Some people have suggested putting the Screen name and other stuff into a variable and then just using a terinary operator or conditional to manage the output. This is a really clean solution, and after some tweaking, I ended up with:
const UserAvatar = ({id, screenName, displayUserLink}: UserAvatar) => {

const content = (
  <div css={styles.userTag}>
    <div>{screenName} AND A WHOLE BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF...</div>
  </div>
);

return (
    {displayUserLink && (<Link to={'/users/' + id}>{content}</Link>)}
    {!displayUserLink && (content)}
);

};
The subtile point to note is that content is rendered correctly in the link as '{content}', but simply as 'content' below.

Put the contents of the link in a variable, and conditionally return either just that content, or the content variable wrapped in a link.

Don't include the Link in the component. Make a wrapper for the component that just does return ({displayUserLink ? (<Link><UserAvatar/></Link>) : (<UserAvatar>)})

A cleaner way would be to assign the content to a variable, the optionally include the Link wrappers.
interface UserAvatar {
  id: number;
  screenName: string;
  displayUserLink: boolean;
}

const UserAvatar = ({ id, screenName, displayUserLink }: UserAvatar) => {
  const content = <div>{screenName} AND A WHOLE BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF...</div>

  return (
    {displayUserLink ? <Link>content</Link> : content }
  );
};

export default UserAvatar;


Great suggestion, but I get an error when I try this: 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {content}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.' Looks like react thinks I am trying to build an array of controls for some reason?

Then you're trying to render multiple blocks next to each other in the content, like
<div>abc</div><div>def</div>. They need to be grouped under one parent, like this <><div>abc</div><div>def</div></>

content is a JSX object, not a string. This is basically what was described in the duplicate.

The linked duplicate describes how to conditionally render a component. The OP already knows how to do that as evidenced by the sample code. My example attempts to answer his question about cleanly rendering a large inner component which OP was attempting to do with separated start and end tags.

Ok found the problem. content needed some brackets to get it working correctly. Thx!

You can for example conditionally render the component as follows:


interface UserAvatar {
  id: number;
  screenName: string;
  displayUserLink: boolean;
}

const UserAvatar = ({ id, screenName, displayUserLink }: UserAvatar) => {
  {displayUserLink ?
  (
 <Link to={'/users/' + id} >
    <div>{screenName} AND A WHOLE BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF..         </div>
 </Link> ) : (<div>{screenName} AND A WHOLE BUNCH OF OTHER STUFF..         </div>)
};

export default UserAvatar;



